# How to merge two files with ffmpeg without

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation, google-hangouts

I would like to merge two files with ffmpeg, but instead to simple add one video to the end of the other, I want that both videos play at same time with one video using all the screen, and the other a small square at the right-bottom at the screen(it`s something like the hangout screen).

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after google it for a while I find out a way:

```
ffmpeg -i input1 -i input2 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS, pad=iw*2:ih[bg]; \
[1:v]setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[fg]; [bg][fg]overlay=w; \
amerge,pan=stereo:c0<c0+c2:c1<c1+c3" output
```

Based on http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2013-June/015662.html

Comment: Use `overlay=W-w-10:H-h-10` for bottom right placement. See the [`overlay` video filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#overlay) documentation for additional options such as `eof_action=pass` if you want the overlay video to vanish if it is shorter than the background, or `shortest=1` if you want the output to terminate when the shortest input terminates.